# Laravel Localization Routes in Jetstream & Fortify

Tags: laravel, routes, localization, fortify, laravel-jetstream

I am using Laravel 8 with the Jetstream and Fortify authentication module. All the auth module works, on the other hand I was in the process of making the site in multi-languages, and I found myself with errors in authentication.
My problem today is the following, when the user finishes registering, he must check his email, or Laravel tells me the following error :

**> Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\UrlGenerationException
Missing required parameter for [Route: verification.verify] [URI: {locale}/email/verify/{id}/{hash}] [Missing parameter: locale].**

But, for the others routes like /en/login, /en/register, /en/user/profile ..., they work fine ! The error is just for the email validation, please help, thanks. To have control over my authentication routes, I ignored the default JetStream & Fortify routes in the ***app/providers***

> routes/web.php

```
 <?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function(){
    return redirect()->route('home-locale', app()->getLocale());
})->name('home');

Route::group([
    'prefix' => '{locale}',
    'where' => ['locale' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}']], function(){
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home-locale');
    Auth::routes();
});

Route::get('/index', 'HomeController@index');
Route::post('/map-agents','MapController@ajaxRequestMap')->name('*','map.agents');
Route::post('/map-agents/agents','MapController@ajaxRequestAgent');


Route::group([
    'middleware' => ['auth:sanctum', 'verified'],
    'prefix' => '{locale}',
    'where' => ['locale' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}']],
    function (){
        Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
});

Route::group([
    'middleware' => ['auth'],
    'prefix' => '{locale}',
    'where' => ['locale' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}']],
    function (){
        Route::resource('agents', AgentsController::class);
});
```

> routes/fortify.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Laravel\Fortify\Features;
use Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\AuthenticatedSessionController;
use Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\ConfirmablePasswordController;
use Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\ConfirmedPasswordStatusController;
use Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\EmailVerificationNotificationController;
use Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\EmailVerificationPromptController;
use Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\NewPasswordController;
use Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\PasswordController;
use Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\PasswordResetLinkController;
use Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\ProfileInformationController;
use Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\RecoveryCodeController;
use Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\RegisteredUserController;
use Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\TwoFactorAuthenticatedSessionController;
use Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\TwoFactorAuthenticationController;
use Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\TwoFactorQrCodeController;
use Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\VerifyEmailController;

Route::group([
    'middleware' => config('fortify.middleware', ['web']),
    'prefix' => '{locale}',
    'where' => ['locale' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}']],
    function () {
        $enableViews = config('fortify.views', true);

    // Authentication...
        if ($enableViews) {
            Route::get('/login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'create'])
            ->middleware(['guest'])
            ->name('login');
        }

        $limiter = config('fortify.limiters.login');
        $twoFactorLimiter = config('fortify.limiters.two-factor');

        Route::post('/login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'store'])
        ->middleware(array_filter([
            'guest',
            $limiter ? 'throttle:'.$limiter : null,
        ]));

        Route::post('/logout', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'destroy'])
        ->name('logout');

    // Password Reset...
        if (Features::enabled(Features::resetPasswords())) {
            if ($enableViews) {
                Route::get('/forgot-password', [PasswordResetLinkController::class, 'create'])
                ->middleware(['guest'])
                ->name('password.request');

                Route::get('/reset-password/{token}', [NewPasswordController::class, 'create'])
                ->middleware(['guest'])
                ->name('password.reset');
            }

            Route::post('/forgot-password', [PasswordResetLinkController::class, 'store'])
            ->middleware(['guest'])
            ->name('password.email');

            Route::post('/reset-password', [NewPasswordController::class, 'store'])
            ->middleware(['guest'])
            ->name('password.update');
        }

    // Registration...
        if (Features::enabled(Features::registration())) {
            if ($enableViews) {
                Route::get('/register', [RegisteredUserController::class, 'create'])
                ->middleware(['guest'])
                ->name('register');
            }

            Route::post('/register', [RegisteredUserController::class, 'store'])
            ->middleware(['guest']);
        }

    // Email Verification...
        if (Features::enabled(Features::emailVerification())) {
            if ($enableViews) {
                Route::get('/email/verify', [EmailVerificationPromptController::class, '__invoke'])
                ->middleware(['auth'])
                ->name('verification.notice');
            }

            Route::get('/email/verify/{id}/{hash}', [VerifyEmailController::class, '__invoke'])
            ->middleware(['auth', 'signed', 'throttle:6,1'])
            ->name('verification.verify');

            Route::post('/email/verification-notification', [EmailVerificationNotificationController::class, 'store'])
            ->middleware(['auth', 'throttle:6,1'])
            ->name('verification.send');
        }

    // Profile Information...
        if (Features::enabled(Features::updateProfileInformation())) {
            Route::put('/user/profile-information', [ProfileInformationController::class, 'update'])
            ->middleware(['auth'])
            ->name('user-profile-information.update');
        }

    // Passwords...
        if (Features::enabled(Features::updatePasswords())) {
            Route::put('/user/password', [PasswordController::class, 'update'])
            ->middleware(['auth'])
            ->name('user-password.update');
        }

    // Password Confirmation...
        if ($enableViews) {
            Route::get('/user/confirm-password', [ConfirmablePasswordController::class, 'show'])
            ->middleware(['auth'])
            ->name('password.confirm');

            Route::get('/user/confirmed-password-status', [ConfirmedPasswordStatusController::class, 'show'])
            ->middleware(['auth'])
            ->name('password.confirmation');
        }

        Route::post('/user/confirm-password', [ConfirmablePasswordController::class, 'store'])
        ->middleware(['auth']);

    // Two Factor Authentication...
        if (Features::enabled(Features::twoFactorAuthentication())) {
            if ($enableViews) {
                Route::get('/two-factor-challenge', [TwoFactorAuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'create'])
                ->middleware(['guest'])
                ->name('two-factor.login');
            }

            Route::post('/two-factor-challenge', [TwoFactorAuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'store'])
            ->middleware(array_filter([
                'guest',
                $twoFactorLimiter ? 'throttle:'.$twoFactorLimiter : null,
            ]));

            $twoFactorMiddleware = Features::optionEnabled(Features::twoFactorAuthentication(), 'confirmPassword')
            ? ['auth', 'password.confirm']
            : ['auth'];

            Route::post('/user/two-factor-authentication', [TwoFactorAuthenticationController::class, 'store'])
            ->middleware($twoFactorMiddleware);

            Route::delete('/user/two-factor-authentication', [TwoFactorAuthenticationController::class, 'destroy'])
            ->middleware($twoFactorMiddleware);

            Route::get('/user/two-factor-qr-code', [TwoFactorQrCodeController::class, 'show'])
            ->middleware($twoFactorMiddleware);

            Route::get('/user/two-factor-recovery-codes', [RecoveryCodeController::class, 'index'])
            ->middleware($twoFactorMiddleware);

            Route::post('/user/two-factor-recovery-codes', [RecoveryCodeController::class, 'store'])
            ->middleware($twoFactorMiddleware);
        }
    });
```

> routes/jetstream.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Controllers\CurrentTeamController;
use Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Controllers\Livewire\ApiTokenController;
use Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Controllers\Livewire\PrivacyPolicyController;
use Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Controllers\Livewire\TeamController;
use Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Controllers\Livewire\TermsOfServiceController;
use Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Controllers\Livewire\UserProfileController;
use Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Controllers\TeamInvitationController;
use Laravel\Jetstream\Jetstream;


Route::group(
    [
        'middleware' => config('jetstream.middleware', ['web']),
        'prefix' => '{locale}',
        'where' => ['locale' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}']],
        function () {
            if (Jetstream::hasTermsAndPrivacyPolicyFeature()) {
                Route::get('/terms-of-service', [TermsOfServiceController::class, 'show'])->name('terms.show');
                Route::get('/privacy-policy', [PrivacyPolicyController::class, 'show'])->name('policy.show');
            }

            Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'verified']], function () {
        // User & Profile...
                Route::get('/user/profile', [UserProfileController::class, 'show'])
                ->name('profile.show');

        // API...
                if (Jetstream::hasApiFeatures()) {
                    Route::get('/user/api-tokens', [ApiTokenController::class, 'index'])->name('api-tokens.index');
                }

        // Teams...
                if (Jetstream::hasTeamFeatures()) {
                    Route::get('/teams/create', [TeamController::class, 'create'])->name('teams.create');
                    Route::get('/teams/{team}', [TeamController::class, 'show'])->name('teams.show');
                    Route::put('/current-team', [CurrentTeamController::class, 'update'])->name('current-team.update');

                    Route::get('/team-invitations/{invitation}', [TeamInvitationController::class, 'accept'])
                    ->middleware(['signed'])
                    ->name('team-invitations.accept');
                }
            });
        });
```

> app/Http/Kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\SetLocale::class,
        ],
        'api' => [
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [ 
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    ];
}
```

> app/Http/Middleware/setLocale.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SetLocale
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $languages = array_keys(config('app.languages'));
        $route = $request->route();

        if (request('change_language')) {
            session()->put('language', request('change_language'));
            $language = request('change_language');
            if (array_key_exists('locale', $route->parameters) && $route->parameters['locale'] != $language)
            {
                $route->parameters['locale'] = $language;

                if (in_array($language, $languages)) {
                    app()->setLocale($language);
                }

                return redirect(route($route->getName(), $route->parameters));
            }
        } elseif (session('language')) {
            $language = session('language');

            if (array_key_exists('locale', $route->parameters) && $route->parameters['locale'] != $language && in_array($route->parameters['locale'], $languages))
            {
                $language = $route->parameters['locale'];
                session()->put('language', $language);
            }
        } elseif (config('app.locale')) {
            $language = config('app.locale');
        }

        if (isset($language) && in_array($language, $languages)) {
            app()->setLocale($language);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had a similar problem and I don't know if it will help you or not, but in the file:

your-project\vendor\laravel\jetstream\routes\livewire.php

You can modify the url you want to change, in my case it was /user/profile